# Pass date range in URL in Django Rest

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x

I have a JSON structure like,

```
[
    {

        "date": "2017-12-17 06:26:53",
        "name": "ab",

    },

    {

        "date": "2017-12-20 03:26:53",
        "name": "ab"

    },

   {

        "date": "2017-12-18 04:26:53",
        "name": "ab"

    },

    {

        "date": "2017-12-19 05:26:53",
        "name": "ab"

    }
]
```

I am using Django Rest Framework. Whenever, I do a GET request to, `localhost/namelist/{{name}}/` is returns the JSON where `"name": "ab"` .

Now, I want to return JSON based on date range. I will pass the start date and end date in the url and it should return the value within that specific date range, time should be ignored. Also, we have to consider months also, not only dates. Here, in this example, month is same but in real scenario months might be different. Like, `localhost/namelist/{{name}}/{{start_date}}/{{end_date}}/`

If the URL is , `localhost/namelist/abcd/2017-12-17/2017-12-19/` then it should return,

```
 [
        {

            "date": "2017-12-17 06:26:53",
            "name": "ab",

        },

       {

            "date": "2017-12-18 04:26:53",
            "name": "ab"

        },

        {

            "date": "2017-12-19 05:26:53",
            "name": "ab"

        }
    ]
```

views.py :-

```
def get_queryset(self):

    param = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    param2 = self.kwargs.get('ak')
    return namelist.objects.filter(name=param, date = param2)
```

urls.py :-

```
urlpatterns = {

    url('^namelist/(?P<pk>[\w\-]+)/(?P<ak>[\w\-]+)/$', ListViewParam.as_view()),

}
```

I can pass the date in the URL, but what the recommended way to pass the date range ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is the easiest one,

views.py :-

```
def get_queryset(self):

    param = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    param2 = self.kwargs.get('sk')
    param3 = self.kwargs.get('ek')
    return namelist.objects.filter(name=param, date__gte = param2, date__lte = param3)
```

urls.py :-

```
urlpatterns = {

    url('^namelist/(?P<pk>[\w\-\.]+)/(?P<sk>[\w\-\.]+)/(?P<ek>[\w\-\.]+)/$', ListViewParam.as_view()),

}
```

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is move the range to `start` and `end` query parameters, rather than keeping them in a rest-style URL format.

That would modify your url to

```
    url('^namelist/(?P<pk>[\w\-]+)/$', ListViewParam.as_view()),
```

and your view to

```
def queryset(self):
    name = self.kwargs.get('ak', None)
    start = self.query_params.get('start', None)
    end = self.query_params.get('end', None)
    return namelist.objects.filter(name = name, date__range(start, end))
```

by leveraging the [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#range) field lookup

That would require you to move your URL to something like

```
localhost/namelist/abcd/?start=2017-12-17&end=2017-12-19
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define the URL params as follows:

```
urlpatterns = {

    url('^namelist/(?P<pk>[\w\-]+)/
                   (?P<start_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})/
                   (?P<end_date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})$', ListViewParam.as_view()),

}
```

And then in your view:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    param = self.kwargs.get('pk')
    start_date = self.kwargs.get('start_date')
    end_date = self.kwargs.get('end_date')
    return namelist.objects.filter(name=param, date__date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

It looks weird, but this is what you are filtering:

- `date`, because your field is called 'date' (altough it is a 'datetime', not a 'date')
- `date__date` because we want to [cast the 'datetime' into a 'date'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#date)
- `date__date__range`, because we'll be filtering by [date range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#range)

**edit** this solution assumes that you will **always** want to filter by date range; if you don't provide both start and end dates in the URL, it will yield a 404 error. If you want to allow optionally filtering by date range, you should go with [Jason's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47980139/7331040), or check out [DRF's filtering section](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#generic-filtering)